# Resolving MySQL 0000-00-00 dateformat in AWS Glue using Scala

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, aws-glue

I'm trying to create a simple AWS Glue script that would load the data from one MySQL database to another. 
I'm stuck at the beginning, because my source DB is configured to use "0000-00-00 00:00:00" as default values for timestamp columns.

I've tried using resolveChoice to convert the column to string, I've also tried (for a test) to only select columns that are not timestamp, but I always get the same error:

> java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

I can't modify the DB to replace those values with NULLs and at this point I can't modify any part of Glue preferences (to include zeroDateTimeBehaviour in the jdbc string)

Comment: [MySQL: Dates, Timestamps and Lies](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/c2168f2a3f97d170f31d2b89742c51c606afdedf/05_spark_sql_and_dataset_api.md#L479)

Comment: I tried using modified JDBC string, but the error still occurs, I'm not sure if this is Glue related or I'm looking at this wrong

Comment: Glue still doesn't support the JDBC string to convert these defaults to nulls.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to MySQL5.7 or later will solve this issue.

[Changes in MySQL 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sql-mode-changes)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not an option at this time